# Add Active Class to a jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add an active class to h2

```
$('.acordeon').on('click','h2',function(){ 
    var t = $(this);
    var tp = t.next();
    var p = t.parent().siblings().find('p');
    tp.slideToggle();
    p.slideUp(); 
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Great... so what's your *question*?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var t = $(this);
 t.addClass('active');
```

Is this what you want? To add an "active" class on the click event?
I hope this helps.

If you want to "switch" the active class you can use the [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function.
It would look like this:

```
t.toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: yes, but when is clicked in other h2, it should be removed que active class

Comment: Ok so what you need is :
t.toggleClass('active');
Here is a link to the documentation of the method
https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: still was created active class in each h2

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your question then? So I can get a better idea of what you want to achieve :)